# Need Windows Tool for Finding and Selecting Multiple Files within Directory

Tags: windows, search

I have multiple folders, each containing thousands of files with identical names (a file of a specific name exists in each of those folders). I have a list of file names that I want to take out of each one of those folders. Is there a software that makes the process less tedious?

Given a list of file names, I'd like the software to get me those files from a folder in one go.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [Everything Search](https://www.voidtools.com/), a Windows utility which does not search file contents, only filenames and folder names. It is quite fast to find appropriate search related filenames once the initial indexing is completed.

The results will be displayed with folder locations as well as size, date, etc. and can be adjusted/sorted as desired.

Wildcards are also supported.

If you desire to move or delete your specific files, this program may be the solution.

Comment: This tool is a keeper for sure! While it can't search for a list of files at once as I wanted, it could bring up all the files of a specific name across all my folders in virtually no time at all. Thanks a ton!